# Scriptaculous Sortable onUpdate not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui-sortable, scriptaculous, onupdate

I'm having some troubles in using `Sortable` class from scriptaculous lib: it seems that `onUpdate` callback is never called if I use the `only` attribute. Here is a working example which does not use 'only' attribute:

```
<ul id="test">
  <li id="item_1" class="level0">
    item 1
    <ul>
      <li id="item_2" class="level1">item 1.1</li>
      <li id="item_3" class="level1">item 1.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="item_4" class="level0">
    item 2
    <ul>
      <li id="item_5" class="level1">item 2.1</li>
      <li id="item_6" class="level1">item 2.2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Sortable.create("test", {
    tree: true,
    onUpdate: function(item) { alert(item.readAttribute("id")) },
  });
</script>
```

This code works well: the `onUpdate` is called properly, but now, if I change the `Sortable.create()` to add `only` attribute, like following, the `onUpdate` isn't called anymore:

```
Sortable.create("test", {
  tree: true,
  only: 'level1',
  onUpdate: function(item) { alert(item.readAttribute("id")) },
});
```

Does anyone already fixed this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging in `dragdrop.js` source code, I finally found that serialization method which is used to detect modifications on tree was limited to root element (but I didn't investigate why it was OK without `only` attribute).

Based on scriptaculous 1.9.0 version, I could fix it by patching `dragdrop.js`. I found several ways of patching the code:

1. By modifying the `serialize` method: this method creates a `options` object but doesn't use it, except for testing `options.tree`. The options passed to `Sortable.tree` are `arguments[1]` which I guess is a bug. The first patching method consists in replacing the `arguments[1]` by `options` (lines 936 and 940):

   ```
   929  serialize: function(element) {
   930    element = $(element);
   931    var options = Object.extend(Sortable.options(element), arguments[1] || { });
   932    var name = encodeURIComponent(
   933      (arguments[1] && arguments[1].name) ? arguments[1].name : element.id);
   934
   935    if (options.tree) {
   936      return Sortable.tree(element, options).children.map( function (item) {
   937        return [name + Sortable._constructIndex(item) + "[id]=" + encodeURIComponent(item.id)].concat(item.children.map(arguments.callee));
   938      }).flatten().join('&');
   939    } else {
   940      return Sortable.sequence(element, options).map( function(item) {
   941        return name + "[]=" + encodeURIComponent(item);
   942      }).join('&');
   943    }
   944  }
   ```
2. The second method consists in manually adding the `options.tree` value. This can be done in `tree` method like this (lines 877 and 'NEW'):

   ```
   872  var options = Object.extend({
   873    tag: sortableOptions.tag,
   874    treeTag: sortableOptions.treeTag,
   875    only: sortableOptions.only,
   876    name: element.id,
   877    format: sortableOptions.format,
   NEW    tree: sortableOptions.tree
   878  }, arguments[1] || { });
   ```

It would also be possible to fix `findElements` method in order to change the `options.tree ? true : false` into `options.treeTag ? true : false` since `options.tree` is never set, therefore the original test will always return `false`, but I'm not sure of side effects.